# Which SPF record takes precedence?

Tags: dns, spf

A legacy domain has *two* SPF records that are identical except for `~all` vs `-all`.

- A domain should have a single SPF record, correct?
- Which record takes precedence?
- Which one should I delete?

Answer (score 1):

In short, keep the HardFail `-all` one only. Consider also looking at this nice [record syntax guide](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax) from openspf.org.

---

Multiple records, [RFC section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-3.2):

> A domain name MUST NOT have multiple records that would cause an
> authorization check to select more than one record.

This basically mean that you shouldn't have more than one `v=spf1` txt entries in your DNS. If your SPF is too long, you can make use of other txt entries and they will be concatenated.

Selecting records, [RFC section 4.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.5):

> If the resultant record set includes
> more than one record, check_host() produces the "permerror" result.

PermError policy, [RFC section G.3](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax):

> As with all results, implementers have a choice to make regarding
> what to do with a message that yields this result.

This means that the mail will either be refused or accepted without any degree of consistancy between servers. This is not the result intended and you shouldn't keep more than 1.

Fail (HardFail) and SoftFail, [RFC section 2.6.4 and 2.6.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-2.6.4):

> 2.6.4 (-) Fail or HardFail
>
> A "fail" result is an explicit statement that the client is not
> authorized to use the domain in the given identity.
>
> 2.6.4 (~) SoftFail
>
> A "softfail" result is a weak statement by the publishing ADMD that
> the host is probably not authorized.  It has not published a
> stronger, more definitive policy that results in a "fail".

Unless you know what you're doing, you generally want to use HardFail to block unauthorized servers. SoftFail will pass in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only have 1 SPF Record, now you can have 2 if one is a Type 99 and one a Type 16.  Type 99 is now obsolete, but it's still OK to have.

But they both have to be the same, if they are not the same most ESP will fail the SPF. If you have 2 SPF's of the same type, most ESP will fail the SPF, one doesn't take precedence.

Read about: [SPF Records](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/spfrecords/)

~all = means treat the email as a "Soft Fail" if SPF Fails
-all = means treat the email as a "Hard Fail" if SPF Fails

Personally, I like `-all` that's the whole point of SPF which is to tell the mail server you didn't send the email, so it shouldn't be delivered. But you should use a [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/) to make sure your SPF works properly after deleting one. Keep in mind, if you ever send through a third party mailer, you'll have to change your SPF to allow them to send on your behalf.